# jMonkeyEngine 3 with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jmonkeyengine

I've got a problem. I am trying to use jme3 with eclipse and Maven. I am using the m2e plugin (with eclipse Oxygen).

Now, I want to add the jme3 dependencies to my pom.xml. I copied the dependency tags from the maven central, from the bintray repository and even from some custom repos (I also added the repositories to the pom). It won't work.

I worked through the first 2 Google search result pages (actually every link on the first two pages) and consulted the maven pom documentation.

I just cannot get this thing to work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>jme3-desktop</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-stable</version>
</dependency>
```

This is what my pom looks like now (I resetted it, cuz nothing will work).
How do I add this (https://mvnrepository.com/repos/jmonkeyengine) repository to the pom (I must not change anything outside my project directory), so that maven can find the dependency?

I'm sure for some of you this is just a job of a few minutes, but I'm working on this for like 2h now, without any results.

A huge thanks in advance

EDIT:
Checked out this solution: [JMonkeyEngine in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957686/jmonkeyengine-in-intellij-idea?rq=1)

Won't work for (e.g.)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>jme3-lwjgl-natives</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-stable</version>
</dependency>
```

And many others...

Comment: are you getting unresolved dependencies? which part of it wont work?

Comment: Missing artifact org.jmonkeyengine:j-ogg-oggd:pom:3.1.0-stable pom.xml /jme3mavenexample

Comment: This is just an example, there are 12 more. Should I add the full pom.xml?

Comment: no thats not neccesary, have you tried going into the repository where maven references? most likely in C:/users/yourUserName/.m2 ?

Comment: There are two files:
- `jME3-jogg-3.1.0-stable.jar.lastUpdated`
- `jME3-jogg-3.1.0-stable.pom.lastUpdated`

Comment: if you dont feel inclined to use maven you could always just add the jar to the build path directly

Comment: Yes, but I have to use an automated maven build process, so this is why I have to do this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [this page of JMonkey docs](https://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/jme3/maven.html), there is the most common **Maven** `pom` setting for working with JMonkey Engine:

```xml
<properties>
    <!-- JMonkey stats -->
    <jme3_g>org.jmonkeyengine</jme3_g>
    <!-- Check the last version -->
    <jme3_v>3.2.0-stable</jme3_v>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <!-- Repository for JMonkey Engine dependences -->
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- JMonkey Engine dependences  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${jme3_g}</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jme3_v}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${jme3_g}</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-desktop</artifactId>
        <version>${jme3_v}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${jme3_g}</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-lwjgl</artifactId>
        <version>${jme3_v}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

**P.S.**

- For working with terrain in JMonkeyEngine(for example, if you want to access to `com.jme3.terrain` package inside your project) you must add the next dependency

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>${jme3_g}</groupId>
      <artifactId>jme3-terrain</artifactId>
      <version>${jme3_v}</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- For working with `jme3-test-data` sources and accessing appropriate paths from your project(like `"Textures/Terrain/splat/grass.jpg"`), you can add the next dependency:

  ```xml
  <!-- Test data -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.sociaal</groupId>
      <artifactId>jME3-testdata</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.20130526</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

You can find all JMonkey Dependencies [from the previous link](https://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/jme3/maven.html)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it, but don't know if something I may need is missing.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jmonkey.version>3.1.0-stable</jmonkey.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>bintray-jmonkeyengine-org.jmonkeyengine</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/jmonkeyengine/org.jmonkeyengine</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-desktop</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-lwjgl</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-lwjgl</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-bullet</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-jbullet</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-jogg</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>jme3-niftygui</artifactId>
        <version>${jmonkey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```